# Why smartphones keep connecting to servers during network change

Tags: android, ios, sockets, network-programming

I am just a novice starting to learn network programming. I was taught that if network change, the socket will be closed. Partial download will drop because IP changes. But I really wonder, smartphones keep moving from place to place, from a network to another or even 4/5G. Smartphones seem to switch network seamlessly without connection loss. Isn't socket closed and connection lost? Doesn't it require new 3whs for the new TCP connection?

P.S. My guess is that nowadays network is fast we won't notice the new 3whs and connect(). It continues connection like wget -c with new IP, but it is very fast. I don't know if my guess is right. Thank you.

Comment: If the “network change[s]”. Define “network” and “network change” in this context. Moving between cell towers or WiFi APs of the same corporate/school network? Disconnecting from cellular and connecting to a coffeehouse AP?

Comment: Yes, all of what you said, e.g. public wifi -> 4G -> private wifi. Mobile devices keep moving.

Comment: Bzzt: “all of” will exhibit different behaviors.

Comment: Consider that cell phone internet is an extension of cell phone calls. Even when moving between towers there is no loss of perceived connectivity. Likewise, layer 3 has no knowledge of a change that has happened transparently.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handover

Comment: On the other hand, connecting to a coffeehouse WiFi (and disconnecting the cellular) would be a network change that would result in the current connections being invalidate.

Comment: Multi-AP WiFi networks (where the APs are the extension of the same network) also have the ability to handover between different APs transparently. Even when the radio connection switches to a different AP, layer 3 is not aware of this transparent change. However, changing a connection from a school WiFi (assumed to be a multi-AP network) to a WiFi on a different network (ie. disconnect and reconnect) would invalidate the current connections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Firstly**
Well configured web servers(google) allow resume downloads so for such servers your act of switching network is supported it also depends on the client used(the app used to download must support this activity).

**Secondly**
There is a standard that is designed to allow such a seamless handover between e.g. Wifi and cell phone, it is called "Mobile IP". Effectively it works a bit like a VPN. No matter what internet connection you use your public IP remains the same and changing between Wifi and cell phone network is covered by the Mobile IP system. Now we also have concepts of aggressive WiFi/Cell Handover in which cellular data takes over in cases where WiFi signal is low or nonexistent.